# How to convert shp file to geojson with geopandas?

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, shapefile

im trying to convert sho file to geojson with geopandas, but i keep getting erros, and i cannot read it with folium nor plotly. ive been using this code

```
shp = gpd.read_file('file.shp')
muns.to_file('file.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
with open('file.geojson') as f:
  file= json.load(f)
```

Comment: Welcome! please show us full code and full error.

Comment: your code is quite odd.... what has `muns` to do with `shp`.  anyway simplest what to get geojson from a geodataframe is `she.__geo_interface__` no need to use files.  this works well with **plotly** for **folium** use **geopandas** `explore()` it's a good higher level simple to use API for **folium**